# ¿Como acceder a métodos(setters y getters) de objetos de diferentes clases en un arrayList en java?

Tags: java, arraylist

tengo un duda con los arrayList:
Tengo una clase Vehículo, y de ella se desprende dos hijos, uno Moto y otro Auto. Necesito hacer una lista de Vehiculos en general, motos, autos, etc. Paso las clases que use:

```
public class Vehiculo { 
    // ATRIBUTOS
    private double precio; 
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;

    // METODOS
    // Constructor
    public Vehiculo (String marca,String modelo,double precio){
      this.precio=precio;
      this.marca=marca;
      this.modelo=modelo;
    }
    // getters
    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    // setters
    public void setPrecio (int precio) {
        this.precio=precio;
    }

    public void setMarca (String marca) {
        this.marca=marca;
    }

    public void setModelo (String modelo) {
        this.modelo=modelo;
    }

}
```

Luego tengo la clase Motos:

```
public class Moto extends Vehiculo{
  // Atributos
  private int cilindrada;

  // METODOS
  // Constructor - sub class constructor-using super()
  public Moto (String marca,String modelo,int cilindrada,int precio){
    super(marca,modelo,precio); 
    this.cilindrada=cilindrada;
  }
  // getters
  public int getCilindrada() {
    return cilindrada;
  }   
  // setters
  public void setCilindrada (int cilindrada) {
    this.cilindrada=cilindrada;
  }
}
```

Luego tengo la clase Auto

```
public class Auto extends Vehiculo{ 
  // Atributos
  private int puertas;
  // METODOS
  // Constructor - sub class constructor-using super()
  public Auto (String marca,String modelo,int puertas,int precio){
    super(marca,modelo,precio); 
    this.puertas=puertas;
  }  
  // getters
  public int getPuertas() {
    return puertas;
  } 
  // setters
  public void setPuertas (int puertas) {
    this.puertas=puertas;
  }
}
```

Luego en el main creo los objetos de clases moto y auto,

```
    Auto auto1 = new Auto("Peugeot","206",4,200000);
    Moto moto1 = new Moto("Honda","Titan",125,60000);
```

y luego los agrego al arraylist,

```
ArrayList<Vehiculo> arrayList = new ArrayList<Vehiculo>();
    arrayList.add(auto1);
    arrayList.add(moto1);
```

Hasta ahí todo perfecto. El tema es que al querer acceder a un método getter especifico de clase Moto o de Auto, no me deja.
¿Como puedo acceder? por ejemplo no me deja hacer:

```
System.out.println(arrayList.get(1).getCilindrada() );
```

pero si me deja acceder a get o set de la clase padre Vehiculo

```
System.out.println(arrayList.get(1).getPrecio() );
```

Desde ya muchas gracias. Saluos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener dos listas:

```
ArrayList<Motos> listaDeMotos = new ArrayList();
listaDeMotos.add(moto1);

ArrayList<Autos> listaDeAutos = new ArrayList();
listaDeAutos.add(auto1);
```

O si necesitas agregar todos en una sola lista entonces necesitas saber que que estás hablando cuando iteras. Por ejemplo:

```
Vehiculo vehiculo = listaDeAutosYVehiculos.get(i);
if (vehiculo instanceof Moto) {
  Moto moto = (Moto)vehiculo;
  System.out.println(moto.getCilindrada() );
 //aquí con este objeto moto puedes accesar todos los métodos de vehículo y de moto.
}
else if (vehiculo instanceof Auto) {
  Auto auto = (Auto)vehiculo;
  System.out.println(auto.getPuertas());
  //con el objeto auto accesas los métodos de auto y de vehículo.
}
else { ??? }
```

Comment: ¿Que solución hay para un arreglo de motos y autos entonces? Porque si bien lo que propones soluciona, sería como un parche, empieza a ser un código menos mantenible. Tegon una conseconaria y necesito un arreglo de objetos, con ArrayList lo logró pero no puedo acceder cosas específicas de auto o moto, que otra solución puede haber?

Comment: Se complica el diseño porque quieres que una Moto implemente los métodos de un Auto y vice versa. Sería mejor definir una interface MisProductos y que tanto Auto como Moto implementen. Tener una lista de productos (autos y motos) y una lista de motos y otra de autos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo veo es que: 
En la posicion 0 tines a auto1 con estos atributos: ("Peugeot","206",4,200000)
Y en la poscion 1 tienes a moto1 con sus atributos: ("Honda","Titan",125,60000)

Y para acceder a sus atributos seria algo como esto

```
 arrayList.get(0).getPuertas();  //metodos de Auto/Vehiculo
 arrayList.get(1).getCilindrada(); //metodos de Moto/Vehiculo
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes acceder a esos métodos, porque no le pertenecen a la clase padre Vehiculos, son solo de Moto y Auto, como bien te mencionaron arriba, lo único que te quedaría por hacer sería la forma de iterar tu lista de vehículos.

Como por ejemplo:

```
Auto auto = new Auto("Audi", "A3", 4, 1000000);
Moto moto = new Moto("Yamaha", "Ninja", 2, 50000);

List<Vehiculo> vehiculos = new ArrayList<>();
vehiculos.add(moto);
vehiculos.add(auto);

for (Vehiculo vehiculo: vehiculos)
{
  if (vehiculo instanceof Auto)
  {
    System.out.println(((Auto) vehiculo).getPuertas());
  }

  if (vehiculo instanceof Moto)
  {
    System.out.println(((Moto) vehiculo).getCilindrada());
  }
}
```